# "Is" operator equivalent for comparing two arrays

Tags: vba

The following code doesn't work because the operator "Is" can only be used to compare two object.
Is there an equivalent of "Is" for comparing two arrays? and I mean the pointers of the arrays, not (only) their content.

Example of use:

```
sub testMAIN()
   dim arrFirst(1 to 3)
   testSUB arrFirst

   dim arrSecond(1 to 3)
   testSUB arrSecond
end sub

sub testSUB(arr)
   if arr Is arrFirst then msgbox "is the first"
end sub
```

I think I am searching for a shorter form of: "`if VarPtr(lBound(arr)) = VarPtr(lBound(arrFirst)) then [...]`"

Comment: Yes. Varptr(array)=Varptr(array2). Lbound, in the unqualified way in which you use it, returns a long which reports the value of the first index of rank 1 of the array

Comment: It seems that Varptr(array) in not supported by VBA.  This is why I thought to VarPtr(lBound(array))

Comment: Varptr is present, but it is a ' hidden' functin, the same as Strptr and objptr.